# How to parse and insert a line in a file using python or gnu tools

Tags: string, file, parsing, unix

I want to programmatically add `'someapp'` into django settings.py file,  which looks like this:

before:

```
...
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
]
...
```

after:

```
...
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'someapp',
]
...
```

What comes to my mind is the following step:

1. locate `^INSTALLED_APPS = [` string in the file
2. locate `]` string to indicate the end of string parsed.
3. fetch all the items within `[]` to avoid conflict
4. append `someapp` to the end of `[]`

This looks like a simple question, but I still want to know how to do it with best practice.

Although this is about python scripting, Bash script with GNU tools, like sed,awk,grep, are also welcomed.

Comment: well, you have some idea.. why not try it with whatever you know and ask question if you have trouble? I can give you a one-liner with sed/awk but you won't learn much from it... if you know python, then use it... for ex: using fileinput and inplace

Comment: and if you want to try with sed/awk, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns is a good place to start with